# Карты в VisualStudio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Как добавить метку с белой надписью и кнопкой в надписи на карту? Вроде такого:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляя метку по примерам я нашел только такой вараинт:

```
map.Center = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
            {
                Latitude = p.Adress[p.Checked].Latitude,
                Longitude = p.Adress[p.Checked].Longitude
            });
            MapIcon mapIcon1 = new MapIcon();
            mapIcon1.Location = map.Center;
            mapIcon1.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0);
            //   mapIcon1.Title = "Школа № " + p.Number;
            mapIcon1.Title = "Метка";

            mapIcon1.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Resource/mappin.png"));
            mapIcon1.ZIndex = 0;
            map.MapElements.Add(mapIcon1);
            map.ZoomLevel = 16;
```

И выглядит это вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е трудность заключается отображении интерфейса самой метки. Надо чтобы при отображении метки радом с названием появлялась кнопка. Как на примере.

Answer (score 4):

Если вы имеете в виду карты Windows, то есть исчерпывающее [руководство](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/display-poi) на MSDN

Вообще, привыкайте пользоваться справочными материалами - просто потому, что с их помощью простые вопросы решаются гораздо быстрее. И даже большинство сложных вопросов решается гораздо быстрее, если пользоваться справочными материалами.

Comment: Я там не нашел как делать кастомизацию меток...(